# If $10^e \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $\gcd(10, n) \neq 1$ find the period of $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider $n=3$ so we have $\frac{1}{3}$. The period's repeating string of digit(s) is $1$ since $10^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Now, consider $n = 6$ so we have $\frac{1}{6}$. Then the period of the fraction's repeating string of digit(s) is $1$, since $\frac{1}{6} = 0.166666....$

But the solution to $10^e \equiv 1 \pmod n$ doesn't exist, yet it is clear that $e$ is equal to $1$. How do we find $e$?

Comment: Is $e$ a variable?

Comment: $e$ is the exponent which makes $10^e \equiv 1 \mod n$ hold true for a given $n$, say $3$ or $7$, etc.

Comment: Since $10^e\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, with $e>0$, we conclude that $10$ is invertible modulo $n$, so $\gcd(10,n)=1$. So there's something wrong in the question.

Comment: @egreg: Consider $n = 6$. Then it is not invertible.

Comment: @DonLarynx But surely there's no $e>0$ such that $10^e\equiv1\pmod{6}$. You *can't* have both $10^e\equiv1\pmod{n}$ for some $e>0$ *and* $\gcd(10,n)\ne1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to find $e>0$ such that $10^e\equiv1\pmod{n}$ if you assume that $\gcd(10,n)\ne1$.

Indeed, if $10^e\equiv1\pmod{n}$ for some $e>0$, then
$$
10^{e-1}\cdot10+kn=1
$$
for some integer $k$, which implies (but is not equivalent to) $\gcd(10,n)=1$.

**General theorem.** If there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $xa+yb=1$, then $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

In your case, $x=10^{e-1}$ and $y=k$.